# How does the OS ensure that one process cannot access the base, limit of another process in the global descriptor table in x86 architecture?

Tags: x86, operating-system, memory-segmentation

I was reading about segmentation in x86 architecture and found that the OS allocates segments for different processes. The addresses of segments are defined in the Global Descriptor Table or Segment Table where every entry consists of a base and a limit which helps the MMU map the virtual address of a program to the physical address and ensure it doesn't go outside its allocated address space. The location of base, limit in the segment table for a particular process is decided by the segment registers.

I have two questions:-

1. Can processes change the segment registers? I think they shouldn't be able to but somewhere I read that they can so now I'm confused.
2. If they are allowed to change the segment registers, then how does the OS ensure that processes don't change the segment registers so that they would now be able to access base, limit of another process thereby accessing the address space of another process?

Comment: The normal was is to use paging, and not map the GDT or any LDT into any process's virtual address space.  And of course only to map pages owned by this process into its address space.

Comment: If you're asking about pure segmentation without paging, like on 286, or 386 without enabling paging:  Presumably by putting the GDT outside of any segments usable with privilege level 3 (ring 3).  Segment descriptors have a privilege level associated.  https://wiki.osdev.org/Global_Descriptor_Table

Answer (score 3):

Processes can change the values in the segment registers. A segment register contains a selector into the GDT or LDT. The actual permissions are contained in the GDT or LDT descriptor. A process can only load a segment register with a segment selector that it has permission to access.

An OS using this approach for process isolation would either a) use a different GDT for every process or b) use a different LDT for every process and put all ring 3 descriptors in the LDT. In this case, only ring 0 descriptors would go in the GDT and ring 3 code would not be able to load any GDT selectors.

Modern OSes do not use the segmentation mechanism to provide isolation between processes. Instead all processes use the same segment descriptors, which have a base of 0 and a limit of FFFFFFFF. (In 64-bit mode, the segment base and limit in the descriptor are ignored.)  Instead, the OS uses paging, so that address 400000, for example, is accessible by every process but it is mapped to a different physical address in every process.